# I am unable to open up a new activity for an EndingScreen for my game

Tags: java, android, android-gameactivity

So I am a new programmer and I have a project due, so I was working on developing a basic game, the problem is once the player dies its supposed to open up a new activity for the ending screen so that i can take them back to the menu whilst also recording their records, however once the player dies no matter what I do it just crashes the App.

This is the code(its messy ik but i've been trying to solve this for a while so i got desperate):

```java
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        // Draw Tilemap
        tilemap.draw(canvas, gameDisplay);

        // Draw game objects
        player.draw(canvas, gameDisplay);

        for (Enemy enemy : enemyList) {
            enemy.draw(canvas, gameDisplay);
        }

        for (Hex hex : hexList) {
            hex.draw(canvas, gameDisplay);
        }

        // Draw game panels
        joystick.draw(canvas);
        performance.draw(canvas);

        // Draw Game over if the player is dead

//this is where i need help

        if (player.getHealthPoints() <= 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.getContext(), EndScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra("score", gameLoop.getCurrentKillCount()); // add any necessary data
            //startActivity(intent);
            playerDead = true;
            playerHasFallen();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            //gameOver.draw(canvas);
            //mainActivity.gameOver();
            //endScreen.gameIsOver();
        }
    }


    public void update() {
        // Stop updating the game if the player is dead
        if (player.getHealthPoints() <= 0) {

            playerDead = true;
            //pause();
            return;
        }

        // Update game state
        joystick.update();
        player.update();

        // Spawn enemy
        if(Enemy.readyToSpawn()) {
            enemyList.add(new Enemy(getContext(), player));
        }

        // Update states of all enemies
        for (Enemy enemy : enemyList) {
            enemy.update();
        }

        // Update states of all spells
        while (numberOfSpellsToCast > 0) {
            hexList.add(new Hex(getContext(), player));
            numberOfSpellsToCast --;
        }
        for (Hex hex : hexList) {
            hex.update();
        }

        // Iterate through enemyList and check if any Enemies have collided with the player
        Iterator<Enemy> iteratorEnemy = enemyList.iterator();
        while (iteratorEnemy.hasNext()) {
            Circle enemy = iteratorEnemy.next();
            if (Circle.isColliding(enemy, player)) {
                // Remove enemy if it collides with the player
                iteratorEnemy.remove();
                player.setHealthPoints(player.getHealthPoints() - monsterTypeADmg);
                //if (playerHasFallen() == true) {break;}
                continue;
            }

            Iterator<Hex> iteratorHex = hexList.iterator();
            while (iteratorHex.hasNext()) {
                Circle hex = iteratorHex.next();
                // remove hexes if it collides with something
                if (Circle.isColliding(hex, enemy)) {
                    iteratorHex.remove();
                    iteratorEnemy.remove();
                    gameLoop.increaseKillCount();
                    increaseMultiplier();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        gameDisplay.update();
    }

    //public void playerDead() {
      //  endScreen.gameIsOver();

    //}

    public boolean playerHasFallen(){
        if (playerDead == true){ return true;}
        return false;
    }
    public boolean isPlayerAlive(){
        if (playerDead == false) {return true;}
        return false;
    }



    public int increaseMultiplier(){

        if(gameLoop.killCount >= difficulty+10) {
            difficulty++;
        }
        //if (gameLoop.increaseKillCount() )
        //monsterTypeADmg++;
        return difficulty;

    }
    public int getMultiplier(){
        return difficulty;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnCreateContextMenuListener(OnCreateContextMenuListener l) {
        super.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(l);

    }

    public void pause() {
        gameLoop.stopLoop();
        gameWindow.setEndScreen();
    }
}




I've tried various different methods to activate a different activity I've tried,

if (playerHealth <= 0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EndingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("score", playerScore); // add any necessary data
    startActivity(intent);
}


Intent intent = new Intent(this, EndScreenActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);


public void openEndScreen(View view) {
        Intent endScreen = new Intent(context,EndScreen.class);
        context.startActivity(endScreen);
    }
```

I've tried calling it from other classes i've tried using different code but no matter what i did the most i got was a black screen (after the canvas turned transparent)

(my bad here is the logcat; FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
Process: com.example.lostc, PID: 3626
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:130)
at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:5688)
at com.example.lostc.GameOver.returnToMenu(GameOver.java:24)
at com.example.lostc.Game.draw(Game.java:225)
at com.example.lostc.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:75))

Comment: Could you also post the crash log from your Logcat please?

Comment: How do you know the error isn't in the EndScreen activity (which you didn't include here)? Always include the errors from Logcat if the app is crashing...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to give a concrete answer without seeing a stack trace, but have you made sure to add `EndScreen` Activity to the `AndroidManifest.xml` as an `<activity>` tag?

Comment: sorry i forgot to include the LogCat but ive added it now, and yes i've put it into the AndroidManifest yet it still did nothing...

Comment: i can see there is a NullPointerException which is rather common, but it's difficult to pinpoint the origin as im unable run your code. lets try replacing the first parameter of the intent from ```this.getContext()``` to ```YourCurrentActivityName.this```. Also, i cant tell how youre simulating a game loop, the NPE may be caused by multithreading issues. either way it difficult to say without being able to run the code